# pitch accents dictionary/extension

Tags: pitch-accent

is there a website that add pitch accent to the text given by the users.I know kanshudo,which has a pitch accent dictionary but it can't display the pitch accent of the whole passage i paste in.

Comment: Asking for resource is [off-topic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/797#797) here. That said, given that text-to-voice conversion is far from perfect yet, I strongly doubt any tool with enough reliability exists out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you want: [Prosody Tutor
Suzuki-kun](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/phrasing)

Keep in mind it's not perfect and by knowing a couple rules you can "graduate" from it pretty easily.